# Is there a better or more efficient way to code this?

Tags: python, regex, html-table, export-to-csv

```
import re
fr=open("test.html",'r')
i,j,tablestart=0,0,0
str=""
p=re.compile("<td.*?>(.*?)<\/td>")
for line in fr:
    if "<table" in line:
        tablestart=1
    elif "</table>" in line and tablestart==1:
        j,tablestart=0,0
    m=p.search(line)
    if m and tablestart==1:
        str+='"' + m.group(1) + '"' + ","
    if "</tr>" in line and tablestart==1:
        print(str)
        str=""
```

The code is creating csv file from html table.
Is there a better or more efficient way to code this?
I'm not looking for any html parsers.

Comment: "I'm not looking for any html parsers." - why? _That_ would be a better way.

Comment: I like to code something i need first before using other's code. i have a problem if there are two <td> in one line any suggestions?

Comment: your code assumes that the html is split by newlines which is not always true, the whole table can be in one line. i'd go for parsers too.

Comment: Please see the highest voted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Concerning your regex. What happens if you html contains e.g. `<a onClick="javascript:alert(3 > 2)">`. Seriously you can't parse a non-regular grammar with a regular expression.

Comment: "I like to code something i need first before using other's code." - In the "real world", you use the tools out there that have solved the basic problems; so you can solve the _actual_ problem.  This is not a new problem; and you are using the _wrong tool_ (regular expressions) to solve a problem that is solved by a parsing engine. If you want to solve it yourself; consider splitting the document into tokens and write a token parser.

Comment: You'll have  more chance at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
for line in fr:
   if re.search(r'"<td.*?>.+?<\/td>"',line):
      line_table = re.findall(r'\>\.+?\<',line)
      var = line_table
      for var1 in var:
         if var1 != False:
             var2 = re.findall(r'\>\.+?\<',var1)[0]
             output.write(var2+','+'\n')
         else:
             output.write(','+'\n')
```